# How to show modal with custom height and width without loosing resizable property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, bootstrap-modal

I wanted to open a popup which loads another web page in iframe and display in modal (bootstrap).

This is achived , but whenever i want to customize the height and width , it creates issues.

```
 function popupIframe(popupTitle,popupSrc)
    {
        var html="";
        var htmlIframe="";
        htmlIframe += '<div style="padding:5px;">';
        htmlIframe += '<div>';
        htmlIframe += '<h4 class="pull-left title" style="padding:5px;">'+popupTitle+'</h4>';
        htmlIframe += '<button type="button"   class="close" id="clBtnPopup"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>';
        htmlIframe += '</div>';
        htmlIframe += '<div style="clear:both;"><hr class="divider"></div>';
        htmlIframe += '<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> ';
        htmlIframe += '<div id="loading" style="top:45%;left:45%;position:absolute;"><img src="'+theme_root+'/images/app/loading-flat.gif" class="img-responsive" title="loading.." alt="loading.."/><p class="text-center">loading..</p></div>';
        htmlIframe += '<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="'+popupSrc+'" id="popIfr" style="display:none;"></iframe>';
        htmlIframe += '</div>';
        htmlIframe += '<div>&nbsp;</div>';
        htmlIframe += '</div>';

        html += '<div class="modal fade" id="popupModal" role="dialog" >';
        html += '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">';
        html += ' <div class="modal-content" style="padding:0px;border:0px;">';
        html += '<div class="modal-body" style="padding:0px;border:0px;">'+htmlIframe+'</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';

        $('body').append(html);

        //---------------
        $("#popupModal").modal({backdrop: "static"});
        $("#clBtnPopup").bind("click", function(){
        $("#popupModal").modal("hide");

        $('#popupModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                // do something…
                $("#popupModal").remove();
                });
            });
        $('#popIfr').load(function() {
             $('#loading').hide();
             $(this).show();
            });

    }
```

I need to add css to modal (by jQuery) , such that it will show full height and width on small screen and takes 30 px margin by all side on md/xs or big screen.

Any suggestion to doing these things in other way are also welcome.
Thanks

Comment: thanks @Shehary , but what about sm device , i want full width ??

Comment: Also , if a solution without setinterval something like fix in bootstrap , if there any??

Comment: I put set interval just incase the screen size change, height and width of modal adjust itself accordingly new screen height and width

Comment: without `setinterval` http://jsfiddle.net/mhs9cq43/2/

Comment: "without setinterval  jsfiddle.net/mhs9cq43/2 " , now it is no more responsive , for what i was asking for.

Comment: i will suggest to use `setinterval` because on mobiles screen has 2 different dimensions, in landscape and portrait so it will be good choice to use `setinterval` if user on mobile switch from landscape to portrait and modal adjust it's height and width accordingly

Comment: @Shehary , is there a way to bind a resize event on window to do so ?? I tried , but not succeed

Comment: you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/mhs9cq43/3/

Comment: thanks once again @Shehary , now i  have more things to do more experiments..

Comment: check the update answer, last fiddle with media queries example, happy coding

Comment: amazingly helpful @Shehary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce the modal with the content you provide in question but with jQuery, it is very much achievable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(dimension, 500);

    function dimension() {
        $('.modal-content').css('height', $(window).height() * 0.9);
        $('.modal-content').css('width', $(window).width() * 0.9);
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.modal-dialog {
    margin: 30px 30px auto !important;
    width: inherit !important;
}
```

[Fiddle-1](http://jsfiddle.net/mhs9cq43/)

**Or**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(dimension, 500);

    function dimension() {
        $('.modal-content').css('height', $(window).height() * 1);
        $('.modal-content').css('width', $(window).width() * 1);
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.modal-dialog {
    margin: 0px 0px auto !important;
    width: inherit !important;
}
```

[Fiddle-2](http://jsfiddle.net/mhs9cq43/1/)

**Or**

Add inline styles dynamically use [show.bs.modal event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
       $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
              'max-height':'100%'
       });
});
```

CSS (media queries example)

```
.modal-dialog {
    margin: 10px 10px auto !important;
    width: inherit !important;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .modal-dialog {
        margin: 0px 0px auto !important;
        width: inherit !important;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle-3](http://jsfiddle.net/mhs9cq43/6/)

SideNote: You may need to make some adjustments either in jQuery or CSS or in Both to get the desired result. you can use media queries to adjust the margin according to screen height.